# What is the Chinese equivalent of calling someone "marketable"?

Tags: translation, word-choice, sentence-structure, terminology, sentence

Upon research, something like "***销路***" comes as a result. For example, 'to be marketable' would be "**有销路的**" (yǒu xiāo lù de).

However, this sounds off, as it sounds like too literal of a translation. Kind of like a adjective for marketable items.
It does not sound like a adjective for describing a person.

Example English sentence that I would like translated:

- *"My professor recommends us to go for a second degree after our first degree in taking Masters. It is so that we are marketable to our employers."*

With this sentence, I sometimes gets the translation "**有竞争力**" (**to be competitive**). However, I am looking for a translation closer to the meaning of "marketable".

Comment: Maybe you mean: "My professor recommends that we take a Master's degree after completing our Bachelor's degree, so that we are more "marketable" in the employment market." 可能吗?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

销路

“这会让你更有销路，”她确信。
"This will make you more marketable" she said.

销路

才华横溢是件好事，而销路大开则锦上添花。
It is good to be talented, but it is even better to be marketable.

业绩

为了提升业绩，
In order to make yourself more marketable, (In order to improve your marketability)
你也可以去参加一些证书培训课程。
you can take part in training classes to attain more qualifications.

融入就业市场的方式

从攻取学位证书那刻起，
From the moment they begin their studies,
学子们就应该寻找融入就业市场的最优的方式。
students should seek ways to make themselves optimally marketable.

Comment: I think 成绩 is a good way of describing it as well! I hear it more comment in other instances too!

Answer (score 2):

> 有市場的 (one that has a market for) is the most direct translation of "marketable"

Example:

Famous paintings are always marketable 名畫總是有市場的

> 有销路 is also an accurate translation of "marketable"

Example:

Essential products are always marketable 必需品總是有销路的

Other translations:

Cantonese:

有價有市 - valuable and marketable (e.g. Tuna fish in Japan)

有價冇市 - valuable but not marketable (e.g. Luxury house in China)

> My professor recommends us to go for a second degree after our first degree in taking Masters. It is so that we are marketable to our employers."

In this case, 有市場/有销路 (marketable) is a figure of speech for "attractive" (easy to sell) and you should translate "**marketable** to our employers" to "对雇主们**有吸引力**"

Comment: I see, so as a figure of speech of speech it works as well!

Answer (score 2):

When a marketing agent says someone is quite marketable, he/she means that the person has the quality to draw and get job offers with the least marketing effort, in other words, this person is "quite easy to market". In Chinese, I would say "他的資歷很符合市場需求, **很好推銷**."

The same can be said for commodities - "這商品的功能很符合市場需求, **很好推銷**."

Comment: Interesting, I never knew you could say that a person 「很好推销」! I thought it was only for products!

Comment: @Monokuma In the eyes of the marketers/recruiters, "很好推销" means the candidate/product will be well accepted without excessive spending, a good candidate or product.